# Does a process or thread run on a core?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I am reading the dinosaur OS book and it states that modern day operating systems have extended the idea of processes to include that of threads, which is "especially beneficial on multicore systems, where multiple threads can run in parallel". **I interpret this to mean that each thread of a process runs on its own core.**

However, the book also states that each CPU core can run one process at a time. To me, this sounds inconsistent with the fact that multiple threads belonging to a single process can run simultaneously on each core.

Is the author using the term process and thread interchangeably here? Can a single process use multiple cores where each core runs one of the process' thread?

Comment: *"I interpret this to mean that each thread of a process runs on its own core."* - Correct.  *"Is the author using the term process and thread interchangeably here?"* - Maybe.  In that particular sentence.  But maybe it is talking about older OS versions that didn't support threads!!  (Classic UNIX didn't, for example.)  *"Can a single process use multiple cores where each core runs one of the process' thread?"* - Yes.  That is what happens.

Comment: For completeness, there are other ways to implement threads; e.g. so-called "green threads" and Java virtual threads.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to know is that a process has two major components:

1. A *memory space*, i.e. a mapping from virtual-addresses to physical addresses.  This is what allows code in process A to e.g. access virtual-memory address 0x12345 and code in process B to also access virtual-memory address 0x12345, and yet neither process interferes with (or even sees) the other process's data because the same virtual-address is mapped to a different location in physical RAM in each process.
2. One or more *execution threads*, each of which consists of a stack, plus a set of register-state values (including, importantly, the program-counter register which keeps track of the next CPU opcode that the thread should execute, and a stack-pointer register that keeps track of the amount of valid data currently held in the stack)

Traditionally (e.g. in the 1980s), processes in many OS's were only allowed to have exactly one thread, but as OS's become more sophisticated, that restriction was relaxed.

Note that given the above, we don't really have to think about what core a "process" runs on, since really the only thing that runs on a core is a thread -- for our purpose, it doesn't really matter whether that thread is the only one with access to its memory-space, or whether it is sharing that memory-space with other threads.

So how do threads get mapped to cores?  In modern OS's, it's done quite dynamically by default:  the OS keeps a list of threads that are ready-to-run (i.e. that aren't sleeping or blocked waiting for I/O), and whenever a core becomes available for use (e.g. because some other thread went to sleep, or blocked waiting for I/O, or simply had its quantum expire), then the OS pulls a thread out of that list and starts it running on the newly-available core.

That means that threads aren't "pinned" to a particular core; rather they can bounce around from one core to another many times a second if necessary.  From the point of view of the running code, it doesn't make much difference whether the thread always runs on the same core or get shuffled from one core to another.

A process that contains multiple threads can and usually will use multiple cores, if multiple cores are available.

Meanwhile, any given core is either idle, or executing the instructions of a single thread (by definition:  a core is the hardware necessary to do that.  I'm ignoring Hyperthreading here, btw, as it slightly complicates that definition :) )